# viewDidDisappear of child view controllers not called when tap on UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with `UITabBarController` and some `UINavigationViewController`s attached with it. Let say, on the first tab of `UITabBarController`, user navigates to view controller A, then to B, then to C, therefore created a stack of `UINavigationController`: `A -> B -> C`.

I need to do something in `viewDidDisappear:` of A, B and C. If user tap on Back button to go from `C -> B -> A` then `viewDidDisappear:` of B and C are called. But if user tap on first `UITabBar` of `UITabBarController`, they will go straight from `C -> A`, and only `viewDidDisappear:` of C is called, B is skipped.

If I use my custom `UITabBarController` subclass and return `NO` in `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`, this behaviour will no more exist, but I don't want to do that, users will have to press Back button many times to go to root view controller. Is there any way to solve this problem but keep the `UITabBarController`'s behaviour?

Comment: You have to rearrange your code so that it doesn't rely on `viewDidDisappear`.  That method is not reliably called (i.e. called in every circumstance you might expect), and this is just one example.  As an aside, the reason it's not called on B is because B's view isn't in the hierarchy when you push C.  If you popped to root controller yourself, you'd see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you keep your bottom bar as None(In view controllers B and C) as shown below.
This will hide the bottom bar from those view controllers and user won't be able to navigate to Viewcontroller A directly from Viewcontroller C. 
The user will need to use the back button navigation to go to View controller A from C.

Which will solve your problem of calling viewDidDisappear.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer that is not wanted.  Quote: *...this behaviour will no more exist, but I don't want to do that, users will have to press Back button many times to go to root view controller.*

Comment: The basic Meaning of viewDidDisappear method is it gets called when the view disappears. If you don't display the view how can You expect ViewDidDisappear to be called. Its basic Lifecycle of iOS App.
Try not to rely much on viewDidDisappear. That would help you :)

Answer (score 0):

when b->c,the viewDidDisappear method has been called,and when c->a,the method can't be called for another time.if you want b to do something,you should keep a weak reference object of b in a or c. Hope that can solve your problem.